# How to create new content or layer in current window?

Tags: wpf

I'm new to WPF, I just can get my application work with web api basic login. when I want continue, I encounter two problems.
1. my application start at first time, I want create several "full view" content at the first start, something like wizard. I search for a while ,found that I can create new window. But I want find a better way, would someone give me a key word for search?
2. I want show my busy indicator message or other error message at the place besides where it is being generate.(ex. click the "login" button, if login failed,show error message besides "login" button)
Is there something in xaml can do as  in html?

```
<div>(visibility:hidden/visible display:none/block)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To your second problem:

There are several ways to achieve this. A good start would be to have a look at the Visibility-Property which every UIElement provides and Triggers. You could create something like this:

```
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding ErrorMessage}">
        <TextBlock.Style>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
                <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Value="true" Binding="{Binding HasErrors}">
                        <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
                    </DataTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </TextBlock.Style>
    </TextBlock>
```

ErrorMessage and HasErrors are properties from your ViewModel. When the login fails, you can just set your message to the ErrorMessage property and set HasErrors to true. Hope this helps...

Comment: Thanks,I misunderstand style before, I think it also can use to solve my first question.